# Flutter: How can I convert this imported CSV data to Map<double, double> for both latitude and longitude?

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

Using file picker, I'm importing a csv with three columns (although i'd prefer only two with lat and lng).

```
 final input = new File(file.path).openRead();
  final fields = await input
      .transform(convert.utf8.decoder)
      .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
      .toList();

  print(fields);
```

result of fields:

> [[1, 33.269271, -72.488985], [2, 31.269271, -73.488985], ...

I was able to convert it to a string like so:

```
  String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(fields);
```

result:

```
I/flutter (19339): 1,33.269271,-72.488985
I/flutter (19339): 2,31.269271,-73.488985
```

How can I get this data to Map<double, double> for latitude and longitude (columns 2 and 3)?

Tried like this:

> position: LatLng(csv[0], csv[1],),

struggling here... Please help

Comment: Map<double,double>  will give you {33.22:-70.48} , I don't think that is what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think it'll cut it off so much. I just need to insert the Map<double,double> var to create a google map marker.

Comment: What is the datatype of "fields"?

Comment: List<List<dynamic>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP made a comment of the datatype of "fields" as:

```
List<List<dynamic>> fields;
```

We can expect that all fields are List of List of doubles, you can try this to get a list of Lat and Lng

```
List<List<dynamic>> fields = [[1, 33.269271, -72.488985], [2, 31.269271, -73.488985]];

List<Map<int, dynamic>> data = [];

int pos = 0;

for(final field in fields){
  Map<int, dynamic> mData = {};
  mData[pos] = {
   'lat': field[0],
   'lng': field[1],
  };
  data.add(mData);
  pos++;
}

for(final d in data)
   print('$d');
```

[image: DartPad test]

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit confusing. How can I access the entire column of latitude in a variable from this? Here's how I extracted latitude for example from a google sheet:     Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)).map(
        (key, value) => MapEntry(
            double.parse(key), value == null ? null : double.tryParse(value))); 

I can easily pass "m2" to a google map marker. I dont think I can do this with your solution. :/

Comment: may be getting it but i'm having to to place everything in the brackets which is a bit weird. testing now 
print (field[1]);